# Can I multi-attack against a Mob?

Tags: multiattack, wrath-and-glory

In the Core Rulebook for Wrath & Glory 2nd edition, the rules about attacking state the following:

> #### Attacking
>
> Normally you make one attack per Round using your Combat Action. Special actions such as Multi- Attack allow you to attack more than one target, while options such as All-Out Attack or Salvo help you to target a single foe more effectively.

Multi-attack rules:

> #### Multi-attack
>
> Multi-Attacks work similarly to Multi-Actions; every additional attack increases the Defence of every target by +2 for the purposes of the Multi-Attack. Each attack of your Multi-Attack must use the same weapon, and you cannot Shift as part of a Multi-Attack. Roll damage once, and apply the result to every target hit.

When fighting a "Mob"-type enemy (which is composed of several entities), it acts as a single entity. Thus can it be multi-attacked or only once per character turn?

Comment: I think these are two distinct questions.

Comment: @Akixkisu You're right, I might as well split them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes even non mob targets

The attack states that you can use a multi attack to attack different targets but you do not have to do that. The multi-attack does not require you to attack a different target neither does a multiaction require the actions to do something different.
Though this has nothing to do with the target being a mob. This line of reasoning works for all targets.

### However this may not be the intention of the rules.

The examples given after multi-attack and multi-action imply that each action has to be distinct. Furthermore allowing multi-attack to be used in this way makes the Salvo Option: 'Spray Shot Vs Mobs' useless. Since in most cases you would kill more troops of the mob by attacking it twice with a Bolt-pistol than shooting at it with a Heavy
Stubber Salvo Spray Shot. And you would not even have to spend ammo to do so.

### But Multiattacking Mobs is explicitly allowed

Today i found this paragraph on page 203

> #### Mobs & Multi-Attack
>
> You can use the Multi-Attack to target multiple
> individuals of your choice in a Mob. When you Test to
> hit as part of a Multi-Attack against a Mob, each Icon
> over the target’s Defence means you hit an additional
> target in the Mob, as normal.